# Huge gap between curve and mesh when using array modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to fit my mesh's created with an array modifier around a curve.
It seems to be going in the right direction, but the array modifier

1) Has a major gap between the curve (the window outline which has the orange highlighted)
2) causes some meshes to be elongated (near the top of the curve)
3) Seems to be creating too many mesh objects to neatly fit around the curve (there will be overflow).[image]

Why are these 3 problems occurring and how can I fix them?
Thanks!

Comment: Set the relative offset to 1.0 instead of 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
So I'm not entirely sure what this is, but if I switched back to edit more, there is a sort of "base mesh" which wasn't really the mesh but some object, and if I moved it along the correct axis, the "array modified" mesh moved accordingly until it fit properly around the curve.